Keyboard on phone going over the viewport in React
When serving my app on a phone, the virtual keyboard blocks the bottom of the page, which scrolls under it instead of not rendering there at all.
This doesn't happen on the simulator I'm using, and I'm pretty clueless.
I tried to use the --vh css variable to control the viewport, but it doesn't seem to do much.
Here is the relevant code
App.js
// App.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import About from './components/About';
import ProjectList from './components/ProjectList';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import BackendHealthIndicator from './components/BackendHealthIndicator';
import BackendStatus from './components/BackendStatus';
import GPTInterface from './components/gpt_page/GPTInterface';
import debugEnvironment from './utils/envDebug';
import VersionData from './components/VersionData';

// Run environment debug on app start
const envVars = debugEnvironment();
console.debug(`envVars: ${envVars}`);

// Your existing AppContent component
const AppContent = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const isGPTRoute = location.pathname === '/gpt';

    // Only show the main app content if we're not on the GPT route
    if (isGPTRoute) {
        return <GPTInterface />;
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Welcome to My Personal Website</h1>
            <Header />
            <BackendHealthIndicator />
            <BackendStatus />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/projects" element={<ProjectList />} />
                <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            </Routes>
            <VersionData />
        </div>
    );
};

function App() {
    // **Added useEffect hook to set --vh CSS variable**
    useEffect(() => {
        const setVh = () => {
            // Calculate 1% of the viewport height
            const vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
            // Set the value in the --vh custom property
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
        };

        // Set the initial value
        setVh();

        // Re-calculate on resize and orientation change
        window.addEventListener('resize', setVh);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', setVh);

        // Clean up event listeners on component unmount
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', setVh);
            window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', setVh);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/gpt" element={<GPTInterface />} />
                <Route path="/*" element={<AppContent />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;


App.css
/* App.css */
.App {
    /* Use the dynamically updated --vh variable for height */
    height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
    text-align: center;

    /* Added flex properties */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* The rest of your existing CSS remains the same */

.App-logo {
    height: 40vmin;
    pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    .App-logo {
        animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
    }
}

.App-header {
    /* Removed min-height: 100vh; to prevent conflicts */
    /* You can adjust the height if necessary */
    /* min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100); */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
    color: white;
}

.App-link {
    color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

MainContent.js
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from './MainContent.module.css';
import InitialChat from './chat/InitialChat';
import { GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS } from '../constants';
import ResponseChat from './chat/ResponseChat';
import useLlmQuery from './chat/hooks/useLlmQuery';
import { useLocation, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShareButtons from '../../share_tile/ShareTile';
import UrlShorteningService from '../../../services/UrlShorteningService';

const MainContent = () => {
  const [isInitialChatDoneAnimating, setIsInitialChatDoneAnimating] = useState(false);
  const [llmQuery, setLlmQuery] = useState('');
  const [llmResponse, setLlmResponse] = useState('');
  const [clearInputTrigger, setClearInputTrigger] = useState(false);
  const [shortUrl, setShortUrl] = useState(''); // New state for the shortened URL

  const queryLlm = useLlmQuery(setLlmResponse);
  const location = useLocation();
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const queryFromUrl = searchParams.get('query') || '';

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === '/gpt') {
      console.log(`MainContent: Query from URL: ${queryFromUrl}`);
      queryLlm(queryFromUrl);
      setLlmQuery(queryFromUrl);
    }
  }, [location.pathname, queryFromUrl, queryLlm]);

  const onQueryChange = useCallback((query) => {
    console.log(`MainContent: Query changed to: ${query}`);
    setLlmQuery(query);
  }, []);

  const handleTypingAnimationDone = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('MainContent: Typing animation done');
    if (llmQuery.trim()) {
      queryLlm(llmQuery);
      searchParams.set('query', llmQuery);
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    }
    setIsInitialChatDoneAnimating(true);
  }, [llmQuery, queryLlm, searchParams, setSearchParams]);

  const handleSendMessage = useCallback(
    (message) => {
      console.log(`MainContent: User sent message: ${message}`);
      setLlmQuery(message);
      queryLlm(message);
      searchParams.set('query', message);
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    },
    [queryLlm, searchParams, setSearchParams]
  );

  const onNewQuestionClicked = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(`MainContent: User clicked ${GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.NEW_QUESTION_BUTTON_TEXT}`);
    setLlmQuery('');
    setLlmResponse('');
    searchParams.delete('query');
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
    setIsInitialChatDoneAnimating(false);
    setClearInputTrigger((prev) => !prev);
    setShortUrl(GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.SHORT_URL_DEFAULT); // Reset the short URL
  }, [searchParams, setSearchParams]);

  // Generate short URL whenever the query changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const generateShortUrl = async () => {
      const query = searchParams.get('query');
      if (query) {
        const fullUrl = window.location.href;
        try {
          const shortenedUrl = await UrlShorteningService.shorten_url(fullUrl);
          setShortUrl(shortenedUrl);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Failed to generate short URL:', error);
          setShortUrl(GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.SHORT_URL_DEFAULT);
        }
      } else {
        setShortUrl(GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.SHORT_URL_DEFAULT);
      }
    };

    generateShortUrl();
  }, [searchParams]);

  return (
    <main className={styles.mainContent}>
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <button className={styles.backButton} onClick={onNewQuestionClicked}>
          {GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.BACK_BUTTON_TEXT}
        </button>
        <h1>{GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.TITLE}</h1>
        <div className={styles.userIcon}>{GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.USER_ICON_TEXT}</div>
      </header>

      <section
        className={
          isInitialChatDoneAnimating ? styles.querySection : styles.centeredQuerySection
        }
      >
        {!isInitialChatDoneAnimating ? (
          <InitialChat
            initialQuery={llmQuery}
            onTypingAnimationDone={handleTypingAnimationDone}
            onLlmResponse={setLlmResponse}
            onQueryChange={onQueryChange}
            clearInputTrigger={clearInputTrigger}
          />
        ) : (
          <ResponseChat
            query={llmQuery}
            response={llmResponse}
            setResponse={setLlmResponse}
            onSendMessage={handleSendMessage}
            onBackClicked={() => {
              setSearchParams('');
              setIsInitialChatDoneAnimating(false);
              setShortUrl(GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.SHORT_URL_DEFAULT); // Reset the short URL
            }}
          />
        )}
      </section>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <ShareButtons shortUrl={shortUrl} />
        <div className={styles.disclaimer}>{GPT_PAGE_CONSTANTS.DISCLAIMER}</div>
      </footer>
    </main>
  );
};

export default MainContent;


MainContent.module.css
/* MainContent.module.css */


.mainContent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #212121;
    min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
    overflow-y: auto;
}


.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin: 0;
}

.backButton {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;

    border-color: wheat;
    padding: 5px;
}

.userIcon {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.querySection {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.centeredQuerySection {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.querySection h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Disclaimer */
.disclaimer {
    margin-top: auto;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #212121;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #a0a0a0;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #a0a0a0;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Responsive Styles */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .mainContent {
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    .querySection h2,
    .centeredQuerySection h2 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .mainContent {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        order: 1;
    }

    .userIcon {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .querySection h2,
    .centeredQuerySection h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .inputContainer {
        padding: 8px 12px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .mainContent {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .querySection h2,
    .centeredQuerySection h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .inputContainer input {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .inputContainer .sendButton {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

I can also give the rest of the code, but not sure it's relevant.

How to make the keyboard not hide anything, but rather have the viewport be smaller when the keyboard is open?
